# Loading html page in div

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to load a HTML page in a div, but i get an error in the console all the time and don't know how to fix it.

```
<head>
     <script>
     $(document).ready( function() {
          $("#load_tekening").on("click", function() {
          $("#tekening").load("tekening.html");
          });

          $("#load_vlieg").on("click", function() {
          $("#vlieg").load("vlieg.html");
          });
     });
     </script>
</head>
<body>

     <ul>
          <li><a href="#" id="load_tekening">Tekening</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="load_vlieg">Vlieg</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kaars</a></li>
     </ul>

     <div id="tekening">        
     </div>

     <div id="vlieg">        
     </div>                            
</body>
```

So when i click on the link i get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///Users/****/Documents/IMD%20-%20Thomas%20More/SEMESTER%202/Animatie/PORTFOLIO/vlieg.html.
>   Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Comment: You should run a server, even locally and especially if using chrome

Comment: @A.Wolff why is so with chrome?..just curious ..

Comment: @Pilot AFAIK, chrome is the only browser using FILE protocol if HTML page run locally from file

Comment: @A.Wolff I can see firefox using same protocol?

Comment: @Pilot I'm not sure for any other browsers recent version, should be checked or better OP should just run a server locally as WAMP/LAMP/etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
     $(document).ready( function() {
          $("#load_tekening").click(function() {
          $("#tekening").load("tekening.html");
          });

          $("#load_vlieg").click(function() {
          $("#vlieg").load("vlieg.html");
          });
     });
     </script>
```

Please use above code.' On ' does not support latest jquery version